# close the JFrame using a button on jinternalframe

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jinternalframe

I am new to Java language.In my project i created a JInternalFrame inside a JDesktopPane that include in the JFrame(A). In that JInternalFrame i created a button that open another JFrame(B). So what i want is when I am clicking the button the Previous JFrame(A) must dispose.

I tried to create an object of JFrame(A) and use dispose method. But it's not working.

This is the code in JFrame(A)

```
private void panelProfileMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
        connection.getData(username);
        Profile profile = new Profile(connection.firstname,connection.lastname,connection.gender,connection.password); //Calling JInternalFrame
        smallDesktop.removeAll();
        smallDesktop.add(profile).setVisible(true);
    }
```

This is the code in JInternalFrame that calls other JFrame(B)

```
private void btnChangePasswordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        new ChangePassword().setVisible(true);
        
    }
```

Comment: Well now I completely don't understand your question. I have no idea why FrameB would need to dispose of FrameA. Also an application should only have a single JFrame. A child window should be a JDialog. Also have no idea why you would add a MouseListener to a panel to handle a click event. A user should not randomly click on a panel. That is why you have buttons to invoke an event. Answer deleted since I'm confused and I think you need to improve your question so you can get a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment you got earlier, it is surely true that you didn't clarify it properly. But I think what you can do is to use `System.Exit(0);` instead of `dispose`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void panelProfileMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
connection.getData(username);
Profile profile = new Profile(connection.firstname, connection.lastname, connection.gender, connection.password);

profile.setMainFrame(this);

smallDesktop.removeAll();
smallDesktop.add(profile).setVisible(true); }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).